# Simple membership provider, AccountController and auth cookie ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cookies, simplemembership

Just see the default code to validate user:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)) {
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
  }

  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
  return View(model);
}
```

When user is validated then user is redirect to a view but no `auth cookie` is dropped in user pc because i have found no code for that.

So tell me `WebSecurity.Login()` function does it internally or do i need to write code to drop `auth cookie` in user pc?

Answer (score 1):

WebSecurity.Login() adds a session Cookie with this name: .ASPXAUTH.

From MSDN Site: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx)

```
public static bool Login(
    string userName,
    string password,
    bool persistCookie
)
```

**userName**
Type: System.String
The user name.

**password**
Type: System.String
The password.

**persistCookie**
Type: System.Boolean
(Optional) true to specify that the authentication token in the cookie should be persisted beyond the current session; otherwise false. **The default is false**.

*When a user is logged in, ASP.NET sets an authentication token in a cookie that lets ASP.NET know on subsequent requests that the user has been logged in. If persistCookie is false, the token is valid only until the user closes the browser.*

You don't need to add anything.

Comment: if anyone need to increase cookie time then how it will be possible with `WebSecurity.Login()` function?

Comment: Then, you need to change sessionState timeout in web.config file.
 

<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="value_in_minutes"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Because the session cookie .ASPXAUTH, has the same duration as one session in the server.